# In Debian Jessie, make allnoconfig and make allyesconfig generate the same .config file

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, configuration

In debian jessie, I've installed the linux source with:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
```

I obtain a file `/usr/src/linux-source-3.16.tar.xz`, I copy it under my home directory, change the ownership and extract it:

```
sudo cp /usr/src/linux-source-3.16.tar.xz /home/orto/src
cd /home/orto/src
sudo chown orto:orto linux-source-3.16.tar.xz
tar xvf linux-source-3.16.tar.xz
```

The I run `make allnoconfig` which according to `make help` should answers no to all options:

> allnoconfig      - New config where all options are answered with no

but if I count the number of yes answers with:

```
grep "=y" .config | wc -l
```

I obtain **6541 yes answers**. Why?

### Edit (1)

This problem doesn't appear with the vanilla kernel.

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
cd linux-stable/
git checkout v3.16
make allnoconfig
grep "=y" .config | wc -l
```

I obtain only **193 yes answers**.

### Edit (2)

It appears that `make allnoconfig` generate the exact same `.config` file as `make allyesconfig`

Answer (score 1):

Debian patches the official kernel code heavily, including the
`config` program [[1]](https://github.com/semplice/linux/blob/master/debian/patches/features/all/Kbuild-kconfig-Verbose-version-of-listnewconfig.patch). This changes how `make allyesconfig/allnoconfig` 
behaves. Also a lot of `Kconfig` files are modified and certain symbols selected without explicitly asking the user.

If you remove all patches with `quilt pop -a` in the source
code of the related Linux package (you can get it with `apt-get source linux-source-3.16`)
you get the same behaviour as with the vanilla kernel.

Comment: Do you think, that's a bug that should be reported?

Comment: You can report it with severity `wishlist`.

Answer (score 0):

`make tinyconfig` is what you want

https://tiny.wiki.kernel.org/

Edit: might only work on kernels >= 3.17

Comment: In kernel 3.16, I obtain `Makefile:548: recipe for target 'tinyconfig' failed`

Comment: Any error messages before that? And read the link I posted, especially about `CONFIG_EXPERT` and `CONFIG_EMBEDDED`

Comment: No, and in 3.16 `grep -R tinyconfig` gives nothing. The problem is maybe coming from this [patch](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/kernel/linux.git/tree/debian/patches/features/all/Kbuild-kconfig-Verbose-version-of-listnewconfig.patch)?